# Android Retrofit Base64 @Body

Tags: java, android, square, retrofit

Hi all i have this code in android 4.3 and i am using retrofit just now but server thrown me an error message 
"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters." When i am using retrofit

```
//Normal HttpClient
//Base64 String
photo = new String(b);

// Creating HTTP client
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Creating HTTP Post
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://beta2.irealtor.api.iproperty.com.my.ipga.local/PhotoService/"
                    + mPropertyId + "/testWatermark"
            );

httpPut.setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPut.setHeader("Authorization","WFdSeW8vTJ1Z3oQlBJMk53VGpaekZRY2pCd1pYSlVXU090");
httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

httpPut.setEntity(new StringEntity(photo, "utf-8"));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);



//With retrofit
@Headers({
    "content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
})
@PUT("/PhotoService/{PROPERTYID}/{WATERMARK}") String uploadPhoto(
    @Body String photo,
    @Path("PROPERTYID") String propertyId,
    @Path("WATERMARK") String watermark);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For general object types (`String` included) Retrofit is going to use its `Converter` to serialize the value. In this case, Gson is used by default to serialize the body as JSON.

In order to upload Base64-encoded data you want to use [`TypedInput`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/mime/TypedInput.html). This tells Retrofit that you will pass it the raw body which is already serialized and an associated `Content-Type` value.

```
@PUT("/PhotoService/{PROPERTYID}/{WATERMARK}")
String uploadPhoto(
    @Body TypedInput photo,
    @Path("PROPERTYID") String propertyId,
    @Path("WATERMARK") String watermark);
```

I'm going to assume that `b` is a `byte[]` in your above example. Here I'm using an existing implementation of `TypedInput`: [`TypedByteArray`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/mime/TypedByteArray.html)

```
TypedInput body = new TypedByteArray("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", b);
service.uploadPhoto(body, "...", "...");
```

Comment: If i want to upload the multiple photos using Base64 then how it possible with above code?

Comment: @JaiminThakkar can you give TypedInput class? , given link is not dead.