# Retrofit2 Post image as base64

Tags: android, image, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

i've been using Retrofit for a long time but after this huge update, it's been little bit hard :) My issue is i need to send a post request as formUrlEncoded within an image encoded base64.

Without image, the below request works just fine

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("mypath")
Call<BooleanResponse> updateUser(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> updatedValues);
```

But when i tried to include image, Base64 encoded as well then i get Internal Server Error -which i know it is not about server side because i have another application calling this service with HttpPost and that works just fine.

This is how i get base64 data from image and i add this into map that i'll pass to updateUser request as well, but that's just not working.

```
public static String getProfileImage(ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

As i searched, i found that Retrofit use some serializations on request via Gson unless i tell it not to do so! [As in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787585/android-retrofit-base64-body)

But i couldn't figure out how to put it as in Retrofit2, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to post Base64 as form field/parameter? or in Body?

Comment: as form parameter @VaibhavA.Jani

Comment: The issue may be your "Base64 String" will be UrlEncoded try decoding it at server end. OR encapsulate it within "POJO(plain java object)" so it will be sent as Json field within Json object and will get serialized properly. TypedString is removed from Retrofit2!

Comment: But i cannot change web service structure, it has to be as in urlEncoded form field :( @VaibhavA.Jani

Comment: do you have access to the server logs? if yes, please post the error message

Comment: No, i don't have access to them i only use them as client.. @Gavriel

Comment: Can you show the code that adds the key/value to updatedValues? You said you're posting images to the same service from other code that works. Can you show the other code? Or can you compare posting some tiny 1x1 image in the 2 ways? tcpdump, or if you can buy setting up a server that just prints out the POST hash?

Comment: Use any proxy app (Charles, for example) to compare what retrofit2 sends with retrofit. It would be great if you will do it on the same image. Attaching logs will help to answer your question. By the way, did you try to send small images?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov yes i tried with small images.. It's https so not possible to track what it sends or receives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. Updated service request as below

```
@POST("mypath")
Call<BooleanResponse> updateUser(@Body RequestBody updatedBody);
```

And created a RequestBody object from updatedValues map and used above request instead.

```
FormBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
Iterator it = changedFieldsMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
      bodyBuilder.add((String) pair.getKey(), (String) pair.getValue());
      it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
RequestBody requestBody = bodyBuilder.build();
serviceManager.updateUser(requestBody);
```

Comment: can you explain what is the contain of changedFieldsMap? Where do you put the base64 string image?